# Log4j2 2.131. java supported version

Tags: log4j2

What version of java supports latest version of Log4j2 2.13.1. Our application is using Java 8. From the official website I have got information for 2.12.1 mentioned as below but not for 2.13.1. Please let me know java 8 supports 2.13.1 version of Log4j2

Log4j 2.12.1 was the last 2.x release to support Java 7. Those artifacts can be found at:

This is the link: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/download.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Log4j 2.3 was the last version to support Java 6 (and higher)
2. Log4j 2.12.1 was the last version to support Java 7 (and higher)
3. Log4j 2.13.0 and newer releases require a minimum of Java 8.
4. Log4j 3.0.0 is still in development and currently also requires a minimum of Java 8 but may end up requiring a minimum of Java 11.

This information is available on the Log4j 2 home page in the [Requirements](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/index.html#Requirements) paragraph.